# Kotlin extension generic function with basic types without reflection API

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have a Java object that has methods `getLong`, `getBoolean` and `getString`. I attempted to make a generic extension function that has a function as the last parameter. Essentially wrapping the try and catch and call to `getString` etc that could throw an exception. I discovered that `<reified T>` as set when calling for example `getIt<Long>() { // do something with it }` needs the reflection api to figure out `T`. I could not do is check nor isInstance. Any ideas?

```
// This is the non generic function version to get an idea
inline fun JSONObject.getItLong(key: String, block: (value: Long) -> Unit) {
    try {
        block(this.getLong(key))
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        Log.w("${ javaClass.simpleName }KEx", e.message)
    }
}
```

The below `when` does not work.

```
inline fun <reified T> JSONObject.getIt(key: String, block: (value: T) -> Unit) {
    try {
        when {
            Long is T -> { block(this.getLong(key) as T) }
            String is T -> { block(this.getString(key) as T) }
            // Boolean is T -> { block(this.getBoolean(key) as T) } // Boolean broken, does not have companion object?
        }
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        Log.w("fetchFromJSONObject", e.message)
    }
}
```

So, aside from the Boolean issue I wanted to have a generic way to call the right type of get by using `T`. I ran into needing to add kaitlin reflection jar to the classpath. I wanted to avoid that if possible.

UPDATE1: The first answer and response using a `when` with `T::class` does not actually work. Thanks for the idea and it helped me look again. The second I found "wordier" than what I wanted, so I ended up with this solution.

```
inline fun <reified T> JSONObject.getIt(key: String, block: (value: T) -> Unit) {
    try {
        block(this.get(key) as T)
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        Log.w("${ javaClass.simpleName }KEx", e.message)
    }
}
```

This looks like this `jsonObj.getIt<String>("error") { er = it }` as compared to `jsonObj.getIt<String>("error", JSONObject::getString) { err = it }`

UPDATE2: This seems like ultimately a better approach, at least for me and avoids the issues with working with generics to meet the goal

```
inline fun JSONObject.unless(func: JSONObject.() -> Unit) {
    try {
        this.func()
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        Log.w("${ javaClass.simpleName }KEx", e.message)
    }
}
```

Using:

```
jsonObj.unless {
    sDelay = getLong("s_delay") * 1000
    wDelay = getLong("w_delay") * 1000
}
jsonObj.unless { sam = getBoolean("sam") }
jsonObj.unless { err = getString("error") }
```

Comment: Please just post your class to point out your problem.

Comment: I updated with sample code, hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks to @nickrack for answering. The second solution works but requires the accessor, which duplicates indicating the type. The first solution does not work with a when.

Answer (score 1):

The kotlin `is` operator takes an object on the left, and a class reference on the right. You can just use a simple equality check there since you already have class references on both sides.

T is still unknown at compile time, so taking `this.get*() as T` doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You'll have already verified the type in your when block so you might as well use it.

As a matter of completeness you'll probably want to also include an else block in case someone calls `jsonObject.getIt<Date>(...)`.

I've also included a second version that takes an extra parameter to invoke, but sounds like a less verbose version of what you originally wanted. It takes the `key`, `accessor`, and `block`, and works on any existing and new accessors added to `JSONObject` in the future without reification or modifications to the extension.

```
inline fun <reified T> JSONObject.getIt(key: String, block: (value: T) -> Unit) {
    try {
        when (T::class) {
            kotlin.Long::class -> block(this.getLong(key) as Long)
            kotlin.String::class -> block(this.getString(key) as String)
            kotlin.Boolean::class -> block(this.getBoolean(key) as Boolean)
        }
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        Log.w("fetchFromJSONObject", e.message)
    }
}

inline fun <T> JSONObject.getIt(key: String, accessor: JSONObject.(String) -> T, block: (T) -> Unit) {
    try {
        accessor(key).let(block)
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        Log.w("fetchFromJSONObject", e.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The top however does not run, @ParameterName T was expected... so changing it to T.Then running this code at least on Android does not work. The `when` lambda is never executed. I put an else in and that is executed. The second version with the accessor does work.